# Having trouble loading web view content properly on mobile - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiwebview, calendar

I am working on an iOS app where i am using a Web View to pull from this [page](http://redeemercdc.org/events/).
After doing some researching, i found that the calendar is a plug-in called [The Events Manager](https://theeventscalendar.com/). On mobile, it does not load properly and shows it as a list instead of the calendar view. However, navigating to the next or previous month shows that the calendar snaps into its calendar view.

Anyone have any tips on how to approach this?

Comment: this is the plugin issue, not iOS app and nothing you can do on client side

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the date control plugin as it doesn't support mobile, and not a bug from your app and the web view at all.

There is nothing you can do from your side (except forcing the page to load as a computer page and not mobile).

Hope this helps!